# If $B$ is a local ring with maximal ideal $n$, and $A$ is a unital subring over which $B$ is integral, is $B = A + n$ (as $A$-modules)?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

If $B$ is a local ring with maximal ideal $n$, and $A$ is a unital subring over which $B$ is integral, is $B = A + n$ (as $A$-modules)?

Not sure if all of these assumptions are necessary. I am just reading a proof in Harris First Course (that finite unramified bijections between projective varieties are isomorphisms, chapter 14), and I don't understand this step in his argument.

Is there some obvious reason why maybe this set is also a $B$-module? It is not clear to me that $n$ would also be a maximal $A$ module, though it is clear that $A + n > n$, since for example $1 \in A$ but not $n$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can consider $A=\mathbb{Q}$ and $B=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3})$ and they both have only one prime ideal $(0)$ but $A+(0)\neq B$.

Comment: Excellent! ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: Thanks. So the assumption that $A$ and $B$ are both finite type algebras over an algebraically closed field $k$ is important. Since then it follows that $B / n = A / m$, hence $B / (n + A) = (B / n) / (A / m) = 0$.